# Email polling: read the subject and sender

Tags: email, xquery, osb

I'm facing a small trouble with the implementation of an OSB service.
My objective is, through OSB, poll an email inbox to read the body, sender and subject of emails and process the data included in that.
I am currently processing the body correctly, however the sender and subject step it's not perfect.

The proxy service polls the mail inbox (request message type: MFL; transport configuration: email), transform the data using Xquery into xml data and routing them to another proxy service.
As I said before, this mechanism is working... However a lot of information is lost (to, cc, bcc, date/time, etc...)

Is there a way to process the email's sender and subject?

Thanks in advance,
Laura

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access email information that is not part of body (~ or attachments, separate discussion worthy) you need to look into email headers.

For OSB Proxy polling emails these come as part of *inbound*.

See *$inbound/ctx:transport/ctx:request/tp:headers/email:** that has values for To, From, Date, Cc, Bcc, Subject, Content-Type, Reply-To, Reply-Address and any custom user headers.